# seems like GPU is not working in AWS Sagemaker Studio Lab

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, gpu, amazon-sagemaker

I've selected compute type as GPU, and opened my project.

but checking the local devices, it doesn't look like any GPU is deployed.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

outputs:

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
 device_type: "CPU"
 memory_limit: 268435456
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 13079107644747151451]
```

How can I enable GPU usage in AWS Sagemaker?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your codes above and this is what I obtain:

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
 device_type: "CPU"
 memory_limit: 268435456
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 1740204898309190353
 xla_global_id: -1,
 name: "/device:GPU:0"
 device_type: "GPU"
 memory_limit: 14463795200
 locality {
   bus_id: 1
   links {
   }
 }
 incarnation: 13861210837196428676
 physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: Tesla T4, pci bus id: 0000:00:1e.0, compute capability: 7.5"
 xla_global_id: 416903419]
```

GPU did deploy and I just trained my model with it. It's working fine. Did you really choose the GPU as your compute type? If yes, which tensorflow version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for you answer. And with several tries, I found it was because I only installed tensorflow-CPU. After installing tensorflow-GPU, it worked same with yours. Thanks anyway!